# strip decimal points from variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, frontend, strip

I have a series of variables that have a decimal point and a few zeros.  How do I strip the variable so it goes from 1.000 to 1?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove decimal from JavaScript number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7641818/remove-decimal-from-javascript-number)

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Simply...

```
Math.round(quantity);
```

...assuming you want to round `1.7` to `2`.  If not, use `Math.floor` for `1.7` to `1`.

Answer (score 40):

use `parseInt();`

```
parseInt("1.25");//returns 1
parseInt("1.85");//returns 1
parseInt(1.25);//returns 1
parseInt(1.85);//returns 1
```

Comment: Best solution if you don't know how many decimal places the number has.

Answer (score 20):

Use `number = ~~number`

This is the fastest substitute to `Math.floor()`

Comment: I guess this is one of the best ways to strip decimal points from a number

Comment: Based on this test, I would say unless you are dedicated to people using your Safari browser... The trade off of "fastest" vs the obscurity of ~~ to debugging is not worth doing this. Math.floor() gives intent as well as performance. Its very important to make sure readability isn't completely tossed out in favor of minor performance gains, I would use this only in an extreme case of performance boosting.

http://jsperf.com/tilde-vs-floor

Comment: sometimes, JS is very cool with the syntax (#SugarCoatingForLife)

Comment: For anyone wondering in 2022, it doesn't matter... as long as you're not using `parseInt`. https://jsben.ch/8H56M

Answer (score 15):

Use `Math.trunc()`. It does exactly what you ask. It strips the decimal.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/trunc

Comment: And it maintains the sign, +/-

Answer (score 13):

parseInt is the slowest method
math.floor is the 2nd slowest method

faster methods not listed here are:

var myInt = 1.85 | 0;
myInt = 1;

var myInt = 1.85 >> 0;
myInt = 1;

Speed tests done here:
http://jsperf.com/math-floor-vs-math-round-vs-parseint/2

Comment: For those curious about the `|` and `>>` operators, you can learn more on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators). Note: `The operands of all bitwise operators are converted to signed 32-bit integers in two's complement format.`

Answer (score 4):

For rounding numbers to the nearest Integer you can use `Math.round()` like so:

```
Math.round("1.000"); // Will produce 1
Math.round(123.4234); // Will produce 123
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need jQuery for this.

You can use [parseInt](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseInt.asp) just fine. From the page:

```
document.write(parseInt("10.33") + "<br />"); // 10
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another nice example:

I often use `Math.round` *and*  `toLocateString` to convert numbers containing decimal places, into a more readable string, with thousand separators:

```
var myNumberAsString = "1234567.890123"              //  "1234567.890123"
var myNumber = Math.round(0.0 + myNumberAsString);   //  1234568
return myNumber.toLocaleString();                    //  "1,234,568"
```

I find this useful when loading decimal values from, say a JSON Web Service, and need to display them in a friendlier format on a web page (when, of course, I don't need to display all of the decimal places).

Answer (score 0):

A faster, more efficient way would be to use JavaScript's [bitwise operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators), like so:

```
function stripDecimals(n) {
     return n | 0;
}

// examples:
stripDecimals(23.245); // => 23
stripDecimals(100.015020); // => 100
```

The `|` (OR operator) will treat the numbers as **32-bit** (binary `0s` and `1s`), followed by returning the desired result depending on the *operands*, which in this case would result to an *integer* stripped of all decimal places.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use something called `Math.trunc()`... put your number in the parentheses. The reason I don't suggest you use `Math.round()` is that it might change the integer part of your decimal number which some people won't want though you can use `Math.round()` if you know you want to get the closest integer.