# How to remove digits after decimal using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am using numeric in an HTML web page. The problem is that I want numbers without decimals.

```js
function copyText() {
  var mynumber = document.getElementById("field1").value;
  alert(mynumber);
  var mytest = parseInt(mynumber);
}
```

```html
Field1: <input type="number" id="field1" value="123.124" /><br /><br />
<button onclick="copyText()">Check Number</button>

<p>A function is triggered when the button is clicked. The function copies the text in Field1 to Field2.</p>
```

Comment: Take your pick: [`Math.round`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round), [`Math.ceil`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil), [`Math.floor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I convert a float to an int in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596467/how-do-i-convert-a-float-to-an-int-in-javascript)

Comment: When you say "still does not work" it would be more informative to tell what you get - error or worng value or what?

Comment: You're first question was about multiplying floating point numbers with integers, and now it's about parsing strings, making some of these answers irrelevant.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove decimal from JavaScript number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7641818/remove-decimal-from-javascript-number)

Comment: consider: parseInt( 2.3*100 ) === 229

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use JavaScript's [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

Comment: He already is; albeit he's not using the `radix` for some reason...though I'm curious as to why he hasn't simply re-used `parseInt()`.

Comment: @Jake - `parseInt` works as intended. It's `2.3 * 100` that doesn't yield what you would expect.

Answer (score 24):

Assuming you just want to truncate the decimal part (no rounding), here's a shorter (and less expensive) alternative to `parseInt()` or `Math.floor()`:

```
var number = 1.23;
var nodecimals = number | 0; // => 1
```

---

Further examples for the `bitwise OR 0` behavior with `int`, `float` and `string` input:

```
10     | 0 // => 10
10.001 | 0 // => 10
10.991 | 0 // => 10
"10"   | 0 // => 10
"10.1" | 0 // => 10
"10.9" | 0 // => 10
```

Comment: Should we really assume that speed is an issue an an operation like this? It's faster than floor because floor handles multiple types. Floor is also explicit in it's intentions. Novel approach though, +1.

Comment: check how to change that in function

Comment: @Aesthete "Floor handles multiple types" – so does the bitwise OR 0: `10|0 => 10`, `10.1|0 => 10`, `"10"|0 => 10`, `"10.1"|0 => 10` … Semantically, `floor()` is better suited, of course.

Comment: Consider the following, `"foo" | 0` and `"0.1234" | 0` both return `0`. `Math.floor("foo")` returns `NaN` and `Math.floor("0.1234")` returns 0. This is a significant difference.

Comment: @Jake - Thanks for pointing this out. The problem isn't in the approach per se, but due to floating point arithmetics: `2.3 * 100 = 229.99999999999997`. I added a disclaimer to the answer nonetheless.

Comment: @Jake This issue can easily be solved for some cases by adding a SMALL fraction to give a little "push" to numbers - assuming you're only dealing with positive numbers. For example, ((2.3+0.00000000001)*100)|0 === 230 just fine.  For all others it simply adds such a small amount that nothing much happens.  I'm building a simulation engine where speed is important, and which does not need perfect precision, and I think this works great for my needs. ;)

Answer (score 5):

In ES6 , you can use builtin method `trunc` from Math Object

```
 Math.trunc(345.99933)
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

```
var num = 233.256;
console.log(num.toFixed(0));

//output 233
```

Comment: Don't use this. 233.9.toFixed(0) returns 234 not 233.

Answer (score 2):

returns string:

```
(.17*parseInt(prescription.values)*parseInt(cost.value)).toFixed(0);
```

returns integer:

```
Math.round(.17*parseInt(prescription.values)*parseInt(cost.value));
```

Remember to use radix when parsing ints:

```
parseInt(cost.value, 10)
```

Comment: `toFixed` has various issues (e.g. `(0.595).toFixed(2)` gives 0.59 in Firefox, 0.60 in IE), better to use `Math.round` or similar.

Answer (score 1):

Mathematically, using a `floor` function makes the most sense. This gives you a real number to the largest previous integer.

```
ans7 = Math.floor(.17*parseInt(prescription.values)*parseInt(cost.value));
```

Comment: still not working for me basically i am setting these value on graph bar

Comment: basically prescript.values is text type field not number i think that may be the issue

Comment: @ShahzadBaloch - Are you sure it's because you're looking for one property called `value` and the other called `values`? If either of these values is undefined you're going to get `NaN` returned. Otherwise is you multiple a float by two ints and floor the result it will _always_ work.

Comment: And add a radix `ans7 = Math.floor(.17*parseInt(prescription.value,10)*parseInt(cost.value,10));`

Comment: i have added code how to change that num value to withoud decimal

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to get value using `parseInt`

Try :

```
console.log(parseInt(ans7));
```

Answer (score 0):

`~~` operator is a faster substitute for `Math.floor()`.

```js
function copyText() {
  var mynumber = document.getElementById("field1").value;
  alert(~~mynumber);
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Field1</legend>
  <input type="number" id="field1" value="123.124" />
  <button onclick="copyText()">Check Number</button>
</fieldset>
```