# javascript format numbers from 8403.361344537816 to 8.403

Tags: javascript, html

I have a javascript to calculate taxes and it works like this

The html form

```
 <td><input type="text" class="input-180" name="pbruto" id="pbruto" value="0"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="input-180" name="pneto" id="pneto" value="0"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="input-180" name="piva" id="piva" value="0"></td>
```

The javascript code

```
<script>
var taxPerc = 1.19; 
document.getElementById("pbruto")
.onkeyup = function(){
document.getElementById("pneto")
.value = parseFloat(document.getElementById("pbruto")
.value) * (1.00 / taxPerc)
document.getElementById("piva")
.value = parseFloat(document.getElementById("pbruto")
.value) - parseFloat(document.getElementById("pneto").value)
}
</script>
```

The problem is that the results I get from calculations are displayed like this

```
8403.361344537816
```

I need to get rid of those .361344537816 and format the number to 8.403 only

Any way to do this?

EDIT
No solutions yet

Comment: You need to provide more information. What are the DOM values of pbruto/ pneto, what determins where the decimal is on 8.403

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove digits after decimal using Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12423755/how-to-remove-digits-after-decimal-using-javascript)

Comment: Ruchard I edited the question now is easy to see. And it is not a duplicated as the solution pointed gives me no solution

Comment: You want to add a dot as a thousand-delimiter?

Comment: yes and eliminate the decimals .361344537816

Comment: Here's another dup: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19840881/1169519 I think that is what you need.

Comment: no working no good solution

Comment: That's _the best_ solution in that answer you ever can get ...

Comment: Did you look at `Number.toFixed`?

Answer (score 0):

Lets say var x is holding the value, try:

```
x = parseInt(x) / 1000
```

Comment: Edited the question to understand were the info is comming from

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to control the code, if you'd use variables instead of DOM to store values. I've re-written your code, and `toLocaleString()` method seems to do exactly what you want:

```js
var taxPerc = 1.19;
document.getElementById("pbruto").addEventListener('input', function () {
    var valNeto, valPiva,
     elNeto = document.getElementById("pneto"),
     elBruto = document.getElementById("pbruto"),
        elPiva = document.getElementById("piva"),
        valBruto = +(elBruto.value);

    valNeto = valBruto * (1 / taxPerc);
    valPiva = valBruto - valNeto;
    elNeto.value = Math.round(valNeto).toLocaleString('de-DE');
    elPiva.value = Math.round(valPiva).toLocaleString('de-DE');
});
```

```css
label {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<label>Bruto: <input id="pbruto" /></label>
<label>Neto: <input id="pneto" /></label>
<label>Piva: <input id="piva" /></label>
```