# correct number format detection separator

Tags: javascript, numbers, format

I have

```
 var value = $120,90
 var value = $1,209.00
```

currently I replace the first case with

```
 value = value.replaceAll(",", ".").replaceAll("[^0-9.]*", "");
```

which gives me that I am looking for: the integer 12090

with the second case I run in a problem however like this. How can I solve this in Javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may modify you regexp.

```
value  = value.replace(/,/g, ".").replace(/^\D|\.(?!\d*$)/g, "");
```

First will replace ',' to '.' and the 2nd replace NON-digit symbols in the beginning of the string and all dots EXCEPT the last one with the empty string. Then use [parseFloat](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parsefloat.asp).

To be sure completely it's better to create a template for data input and don't allow users to enter values in an invalid format.

Comment: Thats it almost. But are you sure .replaceAll(^\D|\.(?!\d*$). ''); is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see how you can make an algorithm work unless you insist that everyone enters dollars and cents. The only option I can think of is to use locale to determine the number separator.

Comment: Tom: I was thinking if its possible to count the numbers on the left side after the coma and in case > 2 then we remove coma.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use the answer from this thread?

[How can I remove the decimal part from JavaScript number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7641818/remove-decimal-from-javascript-number)

They use [`Math.floor()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor) (round down), [`Math.ceil()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil) (round up) or [`Math.round()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round) (round to nearest integer).