# How to convert comma seperated string value to number?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to convert comma seperated string value to a number. The string value I am getting from `DecimalPipe.transform()` method. I want it to be in number so that I can use it in my calculation.

```
  const value = 123456789.789878;
  let res = this.decimalPipe.transform(value, '1.0-2');
  console.log(parseFloat(res.replace( /,/g, '' )));
```

I tried using `+` operator for typecasting. But it is resulting in `NaN`. Is there any other way to do that or with `+` operaton can I do that?

updated example [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7yjfuz)

Comment: Um... Just remove the commas?

Comment: Just remove commas and parse as Int.

    `str = "123,456,789.79".replace( /,/g, "" );
    parseInt(str);`

Comment: what is your expected output

Comment: @JellyFish yeah. I am able to do it. updated the code. My intention is to trim the digits after decimal point. Is there any way I can do it in single line?

Comment: @SoumyaGangamwar I want to trim digits after decimalpoint keeping first 2 digits. In the given example output should be 123456789.79 .

Comment: @NareshShetty If you want to do this in one line using `parseInt("123,456,789.79".replace( /,/g, "" ))`, or If you want just remove digits after decimal then take refrence from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7641824)