# Javascript file messed up and I need help fixing it

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, forms, web

I am new to coding. I am doing some HTML work and today got into JavaScript. I have tried by myself fixing this and trying to get it done by researching many things and watching videos but I still can't get it right.

So what I am trying to do here is a simple calculator of financial returns, I have a constant of 33% return and I am trying that the person can input his desired amount to invest and calculate how much money he will get in return. The simple Excel math is:

```
( 15000 / 33% ) = 45,454
```

I realized that I cant use percentages in JavaScript so I decided to create a constant which eventually will give me 33% (8.25/25)

HTML code:

```html
<div class="col-xl-6 mt-md-30 mt-xs-30 mt-sm-30">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h4 class="header-title">Calculate Earnings</h4>
      <div class="exhcange-rate mt-5">
        <form action="#">
          <div class="input-form">
            <input type="text" placeholder="15,000" value="" id="amount" />
            <span>USD</span>
          </div>
          <div class="exchange-devider">In 2025:</div>
          <div class="input-form">
            <input
              type="text"
              placeholder="45,454"
              value=""
              class="showamount"
            />
            <span>USD</span>
          </div>
          <div class="exchange-btn">
            <button class="calculateNow" type="calculateNow">
              Calculate Now
            </button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

javascript code:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
  const percent = 8.25 / 25;
  var inputAmount = document.getElementById("amount").value;

  function calculate(event) {
    document.getElementById("showamount") = inputAmount / percent;
  }

  exchange - btn.addEventListener("click", calculate);
</script>
```

Comment: You need to retrieve `inputAmmount` on button click, not on pageload (it'll be empty on pageload). You also need an `inputAmmount` button on the HTML

Comment: Beside that, you should use `document.getElementById('showammount').value = ..` not just `document.getElementById('showammount') = ..`.

Comment: @CertainPerformance how do I retrieve inputAmmount on button click?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't put unrelated content about programming and question. Such as "Thank You", "I am new to programming".

Comment: You can store percentages values like this.
use 0.33 instead of 33%
 ( 15000 / 0.33 ) will also give you the value 45,454

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem is here -

```
                    function calculate(event) {
                      document.getElementById('showamount') =
                      inputAmount / percent ;

                    }
```

You need to assign the `inputAmount / percent` to the value of the element, not to the element itself, so replace it by

```
                    function calculate(event) {
                      document.getElementById('showamount').value =
                      inputAmount / percent ;

                    }
```

As pointed out by a commentor, there is one more mistake -
You used `exchange-button` as a variable but it is never defined(and is also not a valid identifier), so also replace the line

```
exchange-btn.addEventListener('click', calculate);
```

with

```
document.getElementsByClassName('calculateNow')[0].addEventListener('click', calculate);
```

Another problem was that you had misspelled 'amount' in calculate function in the `getElementById`.

Also, in your HTML, input element with class `showamount` should have the id `showamount`.

Another problem is you need to retrieve the value of `inputAmount` when the button is clicked inside the calculate function. The below code is working fine -

```html
<div class="col-xl-6 mt-md-30 mt-xs-30 mt-sm-30">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h4 class="header-title">Calculate Earnings</h4>
                                <div class="exhcange-rate mt-5">
                                    <form action="#">
                                        <div class="input-form">
                                            <input type="number" placeholder="15,000" value="" id="amount">
                                            <span>USD</span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="exchange-devider">In 2025:</div>
                                        <div class="input-form">
                                            <input type="number" placeholder="45,454" value="" id="showamount">
                                            <span>USD</span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="exchange-btn">
                                            <button class="calculateNow" type="calculateNow">Calculate Now</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <script type="text/javascript">

                    const percent = (8.25/25);

                    function calculate(event) {
                      // I put inputAmount here and removed it from outside so it will retrieved when the button is clicked.
                      var inputAmount = document.getElementById('amount').value;
                      document.getElementById('showamount').value =
                      Math.round(inputAmount / percent) ;
                    }

                    document.getElementsByClassName('calculateNow')[0].addEventListener('click', calculate);

               </script>
```

Hope this helps :)

btw, your javascript is not looking that bad.

Comment: You should also address `exchange-btn` because it was never defined and that is not a valid variable name anyways.

Comment: @Titus How do I addresss that?, I tried the code from Sanil but still didn't work out

Comment: I tried it out here : https://js.do/code/385511. Still no luck guys :(

Comment: @JuanPabloGaviria Instead of `exchange-btn.addEventListener...` you'll have to use something like `document.querySelector('.calculateNow').addEventListener...`.

Comment: Still no luck :(, and another guy removed the pizza comment, so if you fine with that text me up for the free pizza :)

Comment: I updated my answer with some more changes. It is working fine now. You can try running it by clicking 'Run code snippet' button as well. I don't want the free pizza though, trying to stay off unhealthy food, thanks for the offer though :D

Comment: @SanilKhurana MAN THANK YOU SO SO SO SO MUCH, it finally works and I have been breaking my head all night. Im gonna take some javascript courses soon. By any means do you know how can I make the "showammount" variable only display no digits

Comment: @SanilKhurana (continuation) after the comma for example input 20000 output goes 60606,0606060606 any idea how to make the output more "human readable for example 60,606 ?

Comment: @JuanPabloGaviria Just change ```inputAmount / percentage``` with ```Math.round(inputAmount / percentage)```. There is more information here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7641818/how-can-i-remove-the-decimal-part-from-javascript-number. Also updated my answer