# percentage(12.225555%) to round Angular HTML

Tags: html, angular

unable to round percent(%) from 25.46474676% to 25%  i am unsing below format Please check

```
        <text>{{Actual_Val / HighRangeLimit * 100 | percent }}%</text>
```

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I remove the decimal part from JavaScript number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7641818/how-can-i-remove-the-decimal-part-from-javascript-number)

Comment: Need Angular with HTML code... This like with in SVG

Answer (score 0):

You could try to do the **calculation** inside of `ngOnInit` and then just set value which you apply the [Angular PercentPipe](https://angular.io/api/common/PercentPipe) too.

```
<text>{{ value | percent }}%</text>

value;

ngOnInit() {
this.value = Actual_Val / HighRangeLimit * 100;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With the pip percent use `: '1.0-0'` it will give you **25** instead of **25.46474676**

```
<text>{{Actual_Val / HighRangeLimit * 100 | percent : '1.0-0' }}%</text>
```